# Material DatePicker Format Validation

Tags: angular, validation, datepicker, angular-material, angular5

So I'm doing an Angular 5 app and trying to make the validation for a Material DatePicker (From Material.Angular.IO). So far is properly working for the feature part, but I do also want to avoid the user can write random text or just one or two numbers, I mean, to force him to write a proper format. I've tried with the pattern method of Validators, but without any success. Any ideas?

HTML

```
<mat-form-field fxFlex="50">
          <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="Fecha de nacimiento" name="fechanacimiento"
                 [formControl]="fechanacimiento" [errorStateMatcher]="matcher">
          <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
          <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
          <mat-error *ngIf="fechanacimiento.hasError('required')">
            La fecha de nacimiento<strong> obligatorio</strong>
          </mat-error>
          <mat-error *ngIf="fechanacimiento.hasError('pattern')">
            La fecha de nacimiento<strong> no tiene el formato correcto</strong>
          </mat-error>
        </mat-form-field>
```

And the controller:

```
  fechanacimiento = new FormControl('', [
Validators.required,
Validators.pattern('\\d{1,2}\\/\\d{1,2}\\/\\d{4}')]);

export class MyErrorStateMatcher implements ErrorStateMatcher {isErrorState(control: FormControl | null, form: FormGroupDirective | NgForm | null): boolean {
const isSubmitted = form && form.submitted;
return !!(control && control.invalid && (control.dirty || control.touched || isSubmitted));}}
```

Comment: Are you using the moment date adapter from angular material ? https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview#choosing-a-date-implementation-and-date-format-settings. Because if you do, you can fork it and force strict parsing of date by adding the strict params of moment.js parse method (cf https://momentjs.com/guides/#/parsing/strict-mode/ )

Comment: I'm not using it currently. Will give it a try!

Comment: Gave it a try, but seems I'm having some problems with momentjs imports, my project says the "default" is not exported ;/

Comment: could you add the snippet of your imports? (hard to help you without it ) and the details error message ?

Comment: Hi there, sorry for the late reply. This is my html: [HTML](https://codeshare.io/2j6Xdg) and this is my Component [JS](https://codeshare.io/G7YomE). The error I get is:    /node_modules/moment/moment"' has no exported member 'default'.

Comment: I never used the rollupMoment, on basically use import moment = require("moment"); Can you try this?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I was on vacation, will give it a try and tell you tomorrow! Thanks!